# What's the most efficient way to determine a selling price, given GOGS and a target ROI percentage?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a function that takes COGS and a target profit margin and returns the a selling price based on the desired margin:

```
const suggestedPrice = function(cost_of_goods_sold, margin) {
  return cost_of_goods_sold / (1 - (margin / 100))
};
```

Customers want to price by return on investment instead, and I'm struggling to come up with a way to implement it. Margin is just basic algebra - if i want a 40% margin, it's just a matter of dividing cost of goods sold by 0.60 - but this is stumping me.

What do i need to do to convert my function into one that returns a price based on ROI ("Given a purchase price of n and a target ROI % of y, what should my selling price be?") instead of profit margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/*
ROI(%) = (suggestedPrice - cost_of_goods_sold) * 100 / cost_of_goods_sold
from which we get 
suggestedPrice = cost_of_goods_sold * (1 + ROI / 100)
*/

const suggestedPrice = (cost_of_goods_sold, ROI) => cost_of_goods_sold * ( 1 + ROI / 100);
```

Comment: Of course! I knew it was going to end up being this simple. Thanks.